# SonarQube: Change rules "time to fix" estimation and issue type

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.5

I have created a new quality profile in SonarQube 5.5 and added the rules I want to have with the severity (*Info, Minor, Major, Critical, Blocker*) I want to have - no problem so far.

Now I want to

- edit the "time to fix" for each rule individually
- add the classification for each rule (is it a bug, a violation or a code smell). This should be done on a "global level" for all projects. I know I can change the classification on a "per project" level.

[image: Sonar Rule Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need the Governance commercial plugin to modify the rule time to fix (more precisely remediation cost/function in SonarQube terminology)

  - You cannot change the classification of a rule. You can only change the classification of a rule violation, i.e. issues.